# neo4django: unexpected (?) warning?

Tags: django-models, neo4j, neo4django

I'm not sure why I get this warning; it might well be that I do not completely comprehend the `related_name` concept, but I thought having different `rel_types` would make the above model not ambiguous/conflicting...

I get the following warnings in neo4django:

```
>>> from evidences.models import *
/[...]/neo4django/db/models/relationships.py:180: UserWarning: `evidence` and `evidence` share a relationship type and direction. Is this what you meant to do?
  % (r.name, name))
/[...]/neo4django/db/models/relationships.py:180: UserWarning: `families` and `families` share a relationship type and direction. Is this what you meant to do?
  % (r.name, name))
```

The related model can be found here: https://gist.github.com/szabi/e57f23d76b885d604a36

I think that *neither* relationship type *nor* target model is shared between the relationships with the same `related_name`.

Using Django 1.4, neo4django current from git.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's definitely a conflict between

```
spouses = models.Relationship('Person',rel_type='SPOUSE',related_name='families')
```

and

```
children = models.Relationship('Person',rel_type='CHILD',related_name='families')
```

Setting `related_name` signifies that you want model instances on the other end of the relationship to be accessed by that name. Since both lines are pointing to `Person`, every Person instance would need to somehow figure out if the `families` relationship field refers to rels of type 'SPOUSE' or 'CHILD'.

I'm not sure about the evidence warning, though. If the models are working how you expect, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Ha! I checked the `evidence` warning, saw no conflict and did not care to check `families`! Will you set up a unit test looking into the `evidence` case?

Comment: So, what I'd like is to have in Person an object `families` which is basically a *union* of incoming SPOUSE and CHILD (the other end of the Relationship being always instances of `Family`). How do I achieve this? Would creating an own **Manager** be the right way? Actually, I'll need to have p.families.all() giving all families, and differentiating in the add function: p.families.addAsChildFam(..) vs. p.families.addAsSpouseFam(..), as .add on such a "union" manager is underspecified.

Comment: If you'd do me a favor and raise an issue, I can try to look further into the evidence case. Heck, if you're feeling generous I'm happy to accept pulls, especially confirming bugs :)

I have a similar, kind of strange relationship use case- let me look at my solution and see if it's generalizable. A customer `Manager` will probably be a part of it, but I have a feeling this will be pretty involved regardless. Hopefully I'll have a gist for you soon.

Comment: Issue raised. While I appreciate the gentle hint re pull I'm pretty new to github (while used git on very small-scaled single person projects), so I'm way to new and thus yet anxious using all its great community features. Actually, I'm not even sure I get the lingo correctly. Did you propose me pulling neo4django, fixing it and sending a pull request (this is really out of scope right now) or did you propose me to post the project stub in a repo you could pull as a "testcase" or to confirm bugs? Btw, is there a slightly more private way to get in touch with you, Matt?

Comment: Thank you sir. I was suggesting you add a test case directly to the project, but no worries if you aren't comfortable. Briefly, if you hit "fork" on the repo, you'll have your own private version which you can `git clone`, commit any changes you'd like, and `git push` to. In GitHub, you issue a pull request through their interface after you push to your fork, asking the original maintainer to merge your changes in.

Comment: I've just posted a possible solution to the family modeling problem - https://gist.github.com/mhluongo/5664051 . It's very not-supported / uses non-public methods in neo4django, but it let's you add families to a person like `person.children_families.add(fam)` or `person.spouse_families.add(fam)`, and pull all families with `person.families.all()`.

As to getting in touch more privately, I tweet @mhluongo or you can shoot me an email at mhluongo - at - gmail.